# Can JWST see Proxima C?

Tags: exoplanet, james-webb-space-telescope

I know that Proxima B is too close for Webb. But Proxima C is >1'' away from Proxima. So Webb could see it. There have been some unconfirmed images from earth. Besides there seem to be dust bands around Proxima that Webb may see too.
So is an observation of Proxima planned and when?

Comment: Maybe. You can look through the approved observation programmes at the jwst site and look for exoplanet and disc observations which might fit: https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/science-execution/approved-programs - proxima centauri is not mentioned by name, though.

Comment: There is no Proxima C.  Proxima Centauri is Alpha Centauri C with a capital or upper case C.  The planets of Proxima Centauri are Proxima Centauri b,  Proxima Centauri c, and  Proxima Centauri d, with lower case letters.